# HR with two colors

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, styling

I'm trying to make an hr with two colors on it, one dark red on the bottom and one orange on the top. An image is attached that gives an example of what I'm trying for. Is there any way to do this using pure CSS?

[image]

EDIT: If not, is there a way to set an hr to be an image? Like a png? Something that will stretch for different sizes?

Comment: you can use Pseudo elements and box-shadow added in my answer

Comment: You shouldn't need to use pseudo elements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use CSS with 2 borders like so:

```
hr {
     border-top: 1px solid gray;
     border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

[Example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgfyqdds/).

And to mimic what you have in your picture with text floating on top of the HR, you can do something like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83y2ztsx/6/).

Answer (score 5):

Another solution could be to just simply use a CSS gradient. Like so:

```css
hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #1e5799;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #1e5799 50%,#7db9e8 50%);
}
```

Comment: i totally didn't know you could do gradients in backgrounds like that! upvote for you good sir.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `hr` just a single element (**Div**) with [Pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) like this:

```css
:root {
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center
}
:root:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: italic
}

div:before, div:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 1px;
    background: black;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
}
div:before{
    left: -100px;
}
div:after{
    right: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div>or</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

so if i understand correctly.. u want one hr..with lets say 1px height of blue and another 1px height of red sitting on top of each other..
u can do this with pure css, by using pseudo classes.

```
hr{
position:relative;
height:1px;
background-color:red;
}
hr:before {
position:absolute;
content : ' ';
left:0;
right:0;
height:1px;
top:-1px;
background-color:blue;
}
```